# Select an element of a list under a textbox using Selenium IDE with firefox

Tags: selenium, firefox-addon, selenium-ide

Good morning ,

In a web page there is a field which name is *Street name*:* and when I put in it  only a number , a list of addresses ,which have that number, appears under that field.

When I click on one of those addresses ,this field contains this address, and other fields as the city or the postal code are automatically populated with the values present in the Street name.

Now I want to do the same with `Selenium`. So I want that `Selenium` clicks on one of the elements of the list which appears under the field *Street name*:* after having inserted a number in this field.

How can I do it ?
What should I put in the three fields (Command, Target, Value)?

Comment: Dang no selenium people :(